# how to fine tune gcc optimizations for space and speed

Tags: gcc, optimization, lto

I am compiling some embedded software with speed and space constraints,
using a pic32 port of gcc. Due to the space constraints, I need to optimize
for size (-Os) or the image won't fit (e.g. with -O2). Link-Time
Optimizations (-flto) further reduce the code size, compared with -Os only,
but also reduce the speed significantly (20-25%).

How can I tune the compiler optimizations to find different space-speed
trade-offs that suit my target? gcc has many options and parameters that
may affect speed and size on different targets and the
documentation is minimal. A first attempt at enabling the options used for
-O2 and not -Os (-falign-functions  -falign-jumps -falign-labels
-falign-loops -fprefetch-loop-arrays  -freorder-blocks-algorithm=stc) has
provided no noticeable improvement.

The target processor is a MIPS32 without cache. The application is
bare-metal and I cannot modify it to make it faster or smaller.